# Starting A Second Activity In a Tabview

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-intent

My problem is this:

I have 3 tabs, each with an assigned activity. From one of those activities, I want to launch a second activity in the first activity's view (thereby keeping the tabview visible).

So far, I have tried a few approaches:

1 - adding an intent to the first activity's class and then calling startActivityForResult(). This results in the tabview being lost and the second activity covering the screen.

2 - Using a ViewFlipper and adding the second activity as the flipped view.

If anyone can give any sort of direction on where I should be looking I will be extremely pleased :)

Thanks

Comment: you're going to run into some undesirable problems if you implement this.  the default android tabs are not meant to be used like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John all you are looking for is ActivityGroup here are the links that may prove useful to you

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: Hi Folks, many thanks for your answers. In the end (after much fiddling) I binned the idea of launching multiple activities from a single tab and instead have used a viewflipper - which needed careful thought, but is much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use THis to start the new Activity

View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("tab1", new Intent(this,tab1.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
.getDecorView();

setContentView(view);